# Force executable into memory?

Tags: c++

I have a cpp executable (it contains static libraries), about 1MB in size. When I run the exe, it consumes less than 200kb memory.

From what I understand this means the computer reads the exe little by little when it's needed from the HDD.

I want to improve the performance, even a bit, so, how can I say "load the exe into memory" and don't touch the HDD? Will this bring any performance improvement?

Comment: That wouldn't affect the performance even the tiniest little bit.

Comment: Do you need better performance? Have you looked at your user-code bottlenecks? You're going to get orders of magnitude of speed increases from troubleshooting your own program's issues than rather worrying about loading into memory...

Comment: How does the loading work then?

Comment: Make a RAMdisk and copy the executable onto it and run from there, but I very much doubt it will help. Normally look at your algorithm first, then use a profiler after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** want to do this, you need to touch the memory pages by reading from them. But forcing pages into memory once does not guarantee that they will remain in memory. An apparent alternative solution would be to `VirtualLock` the region, but in practice this function doesn't work the way you'd think (at least on any system where I've used it), even if you have the appropriate privilegues.

Note that the default minimum working set is only 16MB, so for larger executables, forcing pages into RAM will *necessarily* push others (which you need!) out of the working set, so this is in fact an anti-optimization. Unless you have the necessary privilegues to increase the working set size.

It's a bit tedious to find out where the executable's mapping starts and ends. Not that it is impossible, but it's much more complicated than just mapping the file again. Then you simply run a loop which reads one byte every 4096 bytes, and you are done. This will consume twice as much address space, but will consume the same amount of RAM (thanks to how memory mapping works).

But, realistically, you will gain **absolutely nothing** from doing this.

The operating system does not need to load the entire executable and does not need to keep it resident at all times. Part of your executable will be debug info or import info, which the loader will maybe look at once (or won't look at) and never need afterwards. Forcing that stuff into memory only means you purge *useful* pages from the working set.
The OS likely has the parts (or most of it) that are not visible to you in the buffer cache anyway, but even if that isn't the case, you will hardly ever notice a difference.

Comment: Ironically, although I'm telling you that this is an anti-optimization, I've once done (almost) the same thing in a project. Though in that case, the application consisted of _two_ executables where a small stub would prompt the user for some input and would prefetch the real application and a 200MB data file during the 10-12 seconds while the user was typing. Consequently, the _real_ application would pop up instantly once the user was done, and the random reads from the data file would be instantaneous, since they came from the buffer cache. Small differences, but important details.

Answer (score 2):

The OS will load parts of the executable into memory as it is needed. This is where knowing more about the instruction cache might be useful. The idea is that you structure your program so that common code is grouped together. For example, you might have some functions that are getting inlined - in this case the OS would have to load the same code in multiple places which might be slow. By removing the inline you'd have the code in one chunk in memory which would get cached and thus reduce loading time.

I would agree with the others though that this type of optimization should really be reserved until after you profile and know for sure that this is the bottleneck, which is very unlikely

Answer (score 1):

Globally, forcing all of the program into RAM will slow it down.
There are usually large parts of the code which aren't executed
in any given run, and there's no need to ever read these from
disk.

Where forcing all or parts of the program into RAM can make a difference
is latency.  If you're responding in real time to external
events, having to load the code in order to respond will reduce
latency.  This can only be done by using a system specific
request (e.g. `mlock` under Posix systems supporting the read
time extension).  You'll probably have to have special rights to
be able to do it, though.  In practice, it should only be used
on machines dedicated to a specific application, since it can
have a very negative impact on the total system performance.
(There's a reason that it's in the real-time extensions, and not
in the basic Posix.)  Locking the addresses used by the function in memory means that there can be no page faults when it is executed.